# Linux Reading File line by line and reporting

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I have two files which is got after executing few scripts and running few queries,the difference of those two files(Each having two columns,name and number) are now stored in third file
Third file contains three columns **!**

```
!  <Employee Name1> <Employee Number1>
!  <Employee Name1> <Employee Number2>
!  <Employee Name3> <Employee Number4>
!  <Employee Name3> <Employee Number5>
```

How can I read the file 2 lines at a time and report something like

```
<Employee Name1> has different Employee ID.It is <Employee Number1> in File1 and <Employee Number2> in File2
```

Comment: read about `man diff` and `man comm`. Good luck.

Comment: show us the pattern/format  of file2

Comment: @repzero::
File1
`ABCD 1234`
`EFGH 5678`
`IJKL 9012`

File2
`ABCD 1237`
`EFGH 5678`
`IJKL 9013`

File3(diff of above files with blanks and whitespaces removed)
`! ABCD 1234`
`! ABCD 1237`
`! IJKL 9012`
`! IJKL 9013`

Comment: are you comparing file 2 and file 3 to obtain the difference?

Comment: I am using diff -cb and then grep to filter out only the records into file3

Comment: an approach by me posted

Comment: Please show us your attempt. We'd be extremely happy to help you learn how to do this. Most of us would be not quite so happy to provide professional services without compensation.

Comment: Don't post vague descriptions of data like "<Employee Name 1>" and "<Employee Number 1>" - post some actual sample data like "John Logie Baird" and "17". Right now I have no idea if the `<>` are part of the fields or not and if not then I don't know for sure how to tell when a field starts/ends.

Comment: Very ambiguous questions without any solid examples, research effort shown, attempts to solve, etc. One can in theory make a few guesses, but I don't see any point doing so, given op's total ignorance of all the recommendations on how to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

with bash, you can read 2 lines in a while loop:

```
while read -r _ name num1; read -r _ name num2; do
    echo "$name has different Employee ID.It is $num1 in File1 and $num2 in File2"
done < file3
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Glenn.I was able to modify this according to my requirement and get the automation complete

Answer (score 0):

As @shellter suggested, there is almost certainly a better way to achieve the goal you've described, but in the spirit of "be careful what you ask for", here is an awk program which does what you asked for (with a tiny bit of sanity-checking thrown in :-):

```
awk -F'[<>]' '
  function reset() { employee=e1="" }
  NR % 2 { employee=$2; e1 = $4; next; }
  { if ($2 == employee) {
      print employee " is " e1 " in File1 and " $4 " in File2";
    } else {
      print "INTERNAL ERROR at line " NR ": " employee " vs " e1 "; resetting ..."; 
    }
    reset();
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names and IDs contain no whitespace (according to the example in the question comments):

```
awk '
    $2 == name && $3 != id {
        print name, id, $3
    }
    {
        name = $2
        id = $3
    }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{arr[$1]=$2;next}{if(($1 in arr) && !(arr[$1]==$2)){print $1, "has a different Employee ID.It is",arr[$1],"in file 1 and ",$2,"in file 2" }}' file1 file2
```

where file1 and file2 are the paths to your file

example

file1

```
John 1357
Joe 2362
```

file2

```
John 1357
Joe 2361
Joey 25135
Julius 1235
```

output

```
Joe has a different Employee ID.It is 2362 in file 1 and  2361 in file 2
```

Comment: Why does `NR==FNR` get to go in the condition section where it belongs while `($1 in arr) && !(arr[$1]==$2)` gets relegated to inside an `if` expression inside an action block?